# How to change url using Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

[image]I am new in rails, my routes file code is below

```
  namespace :railsapp do
    namespace :v1 do
      get "instapi" => "instapi"
    end
  end
```

this is working fine using below url
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/instapi

I want to change in url like
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/instagram

Answer (score 1):

```
  namespace :railsapp do
    namespace :v1 do
      get "instagram" => "instapi"
    end
  end
```

Comment: I am using Grape API which have below config
    class Base < Grape::API
          mount Railsapp::V1::Instapi
   end

Comment: After this change how can I call url , like I call previous like http://localhost:300/http://localhost:3000/api/v1/instapi

Comment: I have just add screen shot

Comment: Oops. It's under your :railsapp namespace. The correct url will be localhost:3000/railsapp/v1/instagram. You can change the namespace if you wish.

Comment: error comes >> uninitialized constant Railsapp::V1::InstapiController here is my API code
# module API
module Railsapp
  module V1
    class Instapi < Grape::API
      include Railsapp::V1::Defaults

any Idea